# Refactor string concatenation to format in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, string, pycharm, format

Is there any way (with plugin or not) to automatically transform expressions like

```
a = "my fullname is " + name + " " + surname
```

to

```
a = "my fullname is {0} {1}".format(name, surname)
```

in PyCharm?

Comment: I don't not believe there is a way do do this built into PyCharm. Typically if I have old code that uses + before I started using format then I just find all and edit them one at a time. That said you might be able to write some code to reformat your text like a text parsing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No but there is a shortcut to transform that into this:

```py
a = f"my fullname is {name} {surname}"
```

Which is the Python 3 way. You can do that by clicking the blub button in the gutter when you're cursor is over it or pressing `Alt + Enter`.

Read more about [Intention Actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/intention-actions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for exactly this.
I noticed in pyCharm with Python 3.7 I can convert concatenated strings to F-strings in two steps

1. Convert concatenated string to .format() by pressing alt+return
2. Convert the .format() string to f-string by again pressing alt+return